# IOS not able to create privatekey if only devicecode is set on device?

Tags: ios, swift, security, keychain

Im trying to generate a privatekey that only is accessible when either devicecode or current set of biometrics( that is already registered on device) is used.

It works when i have a finger registered on device, then its all good. But if i delete my registered "touchid-finger", and try to generate a new key, then it returns nil

Errorcode is -25293

Code example:

```
func generateKey() -> SecKey?{
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let accessControl = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
            kCFAllocatorDefault,
            kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
            [.devicePasscode,.or,.biometryCurrentSet],
            nil)

    let attributes:[String : Any] = [kSecAttrType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:4096,
    kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [
      kSecAttrIsPermanent:true,
      kSecAttrCanSign: true,
      kSecAttrApplicationTag: "yes.its.my.tag",
      kSecAttrAccessControl:accessControl!]]
      let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as CFDictionary, &error)
     if(error != nil || privateKey == nil) {
      fatalError("explode Kittens")
     }
     return privateKey
}
```

fyi.Its actually works on simulators but not on real devices.

Am i doing something wrong? Is this working as intended? is it a bug? (sooo many questions :D )

Comment: You probably want the `.userPresence` flag. `.biometryCurrentSet` invalidates the item if the biometric database is changed.

Comment: I want it to be invalidated if a new finger is added. So no, do not want to use userPresence. But userPresence works when  generating Key... So im leaning towards ios bug

Comment: What error do you get back when the key creation fails?

Comment: errorcode -25293 key generation failed. 
if the error code is same as OSStatus code , then i belive its a 
`public var errSecAuthFailed: OSStatus { get } 
/* The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct. */ ` . Which make no sense? the device is unlocked with pin.

Comment: Can you check if the call to `SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags` itself also generates an error?

Comment: seems like SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags itself works fine as far as i can see..

Comment: @codaR0y Did you find a solution in the meantime? Running into exactly the same, SecItemAdd fails when using `.biometryCurrentSet` with `.devicePasscode` (and `.or`) - but just when Device has not enabled Biometry (iOS 14.4).

Comment: @FrederikWinkelsdorf sry, no, even created a ticket with apple.Their answer was: 
"problem relates to how the item is /created/, and that’s not what these flags control.  Indeed, for `.biometryCurrentSet` to have any meaning at the time of use, there must actually be a current set of biometrics at the time of creation, and I think that’s the source of the `errSecAuthFailed`

My recommendation is manually fall back to using just `.devicePasscode` if there’s no biometrics available.  Two ways:
A. Catch the error and retry
B. Preflight the request using the LocalAuthentication framework
"

Comment: @codaR0y That's what I thought, `.biometryCurrentSet` makes no sense, if biometry is currently not enrolled so either go testing and provide a fallback or - what I use now - go for `.userPresence` which takes Passcode and Biometry into account (in fact it's documented as a combination of `.biometryAny, .or., .devicePasscode`). The only downside I see is that changing biometry not automatically invalidates a given item, but in cases where the user is currently not enrolled to it, that's probably the best. Thanks for the clarification and especially providing the feedback from Apple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The problem relates to how the item is /created/, and that’s not what these flags control.

Indeed, for .biometryCurrentSet to have any meaning at the time of use, there must actually be a current set of biometrics at the time of creation, and I think that’s the source of the errSecAuthFailed.

My recommendation is manually fall back to using just .devicePasscode if there’s no biometrics available. Two ways: A. Catch the error and retry B. Preflight the request using the LocalAuthentication framework."

Apple says no can do :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm generating a private key, you need to add in ACL object parameter kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly. This will allow you to get a private key using a passcode or biometric data.

```
    guard let aclObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
        kCFAllocatorDefault, kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
        [.userPresence, .privateKeyUsage], nil) else {
        return ""
    }
    // private key parameters
    let privateKeyParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrAccessControl as String:    aclObject as AnyObject, //protect with touch id
        kSecAttrIsPermanent as String:      true as AnyObject
        ]

    // global parameters for our key generation
    let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrTokenID as String:          kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
        kSecAttrKeyType as String:          kSecMessECCKeyType,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:    kSecMessECCKeySize as AnyObject,
        kSecAttrLabel as String:            kSecMessECCSignLabel as AnyObject,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String:      privateKeyParams as AnyObject
    ]

    guard let eCCPrivKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(parameters as CFDictionary, nil) else {
        print("ECC KeyGen Error!")
        return ""
    }

    guard let eCCPubKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(eCCPrivKey) else {
        print("ECC Pub KeyGen Error")
        return ""
    }
```

Comment: If i change mine to use .userPresence it works fine. The problem is the combination pincode and currentBiometricSet, I want the key not to work if a new finger is added. Then only the pincode should be valid

Comment: I tried you suggestion for fun, did not work (as expected). I would say that kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly has really nothing todo with the problem. The reason it works for you is that you are using `.userPresence` which i can not.